# Is there any native VsCode infrastructure for code generation other than snippets and Emmet?

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-generation, vscode-snippets

I wonder if there is any VsCode API that supports custom code generation other than snippets and Emmet? Snippets work fine in general, but I need more flexibility by being able insert some pieces of text based on a given context.

I tried snippets, which are powerful, but have some limitations.

Comment: ...yes? see `onDidChangeTextDocument` and `applyEdit` and `WorkspaceEdit` in https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api ... does that answer your question?

Comment: what is the context? what do you want to do that snippets can't, have you looked at Hypersnips extension

Comment: Asking about the builtin capabilities of VS Code (and its extension API) is not asking for any "external" resource recommendations... this closure seems inappropriate to me.